# Создание createQueryBuilder внутри SQL запроса для TypeOrm

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Есть запрос который динамически собирается через createQueryBuilder, пример полученного запроса следующий:

```
SELECT * FROM task
WHERE (("attrs"->>'count')::int > 300 ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Но мне нужно что бы данный запрос получился такой:

```
WITH tmp as (
SELECT * FROM task
WHERE (("attrs"->>'count')::int > 300 ) 
ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT * FROM tmp LIMIT 100;
```

я понимаю что в TypeOrm можно добавить limit через **qb.limit(100);** Но мне нужно именно что бы он был для **WITH**. Возможно ли такое реализовать через **createQueryBuilder**  ?

Comment: а разве если написать просто limit 100 в запросе - так не сработает?

Comment: Запрос при генерации намного больше чем тот, что я указал, и так конечно работает, но в силу некоторых особенностей мне нужен limit именно так, как я описал.